# Hibernate Search work with Junit and not work with Pivotal Server (Spring)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Today I have a very strange case (  for me :-)  ) and after some hours of searching, I didn't found any answer.

I build a website with Spring and Hibernate. I'm trying to use Hibernate search (Lucene) without success, or let's say with a partial success .

My entity (inspectionMaster) is configured with some indexed fields :

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name="LGIMAS")
public class InspectionMaster implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="LMISID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="LMRANK", nullable=false)
    private Integer rank;

    @Column(name="LMPIID", nullable=false)
    private Long parentInspection;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="SITID")
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Site site;

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.YES)
    @Column(name="LMVNDN", nullable=false, length=6)
    private String vendorNr;

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.YES)
    @Column(name="LMVNNM", nullable=false, length=25)
    private String vendorDesc;

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.YES)
    @Column(name="LMITEM", nullable=false, length=15)
    private String itemNr;

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.YES)
    @Column(name="LMITDS", nullable=false, length=40)
    private String itemDesc;

    @Column(name="LMSTAT", nullable=false, length=2)
    @Convert(converter = StatusConverter.class)
    private StatusType status;

    @Transient
    private String statusDesc;

    @Column(name="LMRMCT", nullable=false)
    private Long remoteID;

    @Column(name="LMPRTU", nullable=false, precision=1, scale=0)
    private BigDecimal priorityUrg;

    @Column(name="LMPRTC", nullable=false, precision=5, scale=0)
    private BigDecimal priorityCust;

    @Column(name="LMPRTD", nullable=false, precision=2, scale=0)
    private BigDecimal priorityDate;

    @Column(name="LMPRTE", nullable=false, precision=2, scale=0)
    private BigDecimal priorityExt;

    @Column(name="LMSTRL", nullable=false, length=1)
    private String stockRelease;

    @Column(name="LMUPDI", nullable=false, length=1)
    private String updItem;

    @Column(name="LMRCHK", nullable=false, length=1)
    private String recheck;

    @Column(name="LMRCHD")
    private Timestamp recheckDate;

    @Column(name="LMRFCP", nullable=false, length=1)
    private String fullPackIDcontrol;

    @Column(name="LMSPAC", nullable=false, length=2)
    @Convert(converter = ActionsConverter.class)
    private ActionsType specificAction;

    @Column(name="LMTYPE", nullable=false, length=1)
    private String requestType;

    @Column(name="LMRCDT")
    private Timestamp receptDate;

    @Column(name="LMRCUS", length=25)
    private String receptUser;

    @Column(name="LMCTDT")
    private Timestamp controlDate;

    @Column(name="LMCTUS", length=25)
    private String controlUser;

    @Column(name="LMAPDT")
    private Timestamp approvalDate;

    @Column(name="LMAPUS", length=25)
    private String approvalUser;

    @Column(name="LMUNIT", nullable=false, precision=5, scale=0)
    private BigDecimal unitByOuter;

    @Column(name="LMOPCK", nullable=false, precision=5, scale=0)
    private BigDecimal packID;

    @Column(name="LMCFDD")
    private Timestamp coFirstMDD;

    @Column(name="LMCAMT", nullable=false, precision=13, scale=2)
    private BigDecimal coAmount;

    @Column(name="LMCADT")
    private Timestamp customerAnalyseDate;

    @Embedded
    @Transient 
    private List<Whinv> whinv = new ArrayList<Whinv>();

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.YES)
    @Column(name="LMWPLC", nullable=false, length=10)
    private String whmPickLocation;

    @Transient 
    private boolean WHINVExist;
```

I check my Lucene index with Luke and this index if fully correct, filled with needed words ...

I build a JUnit test case :

```
@Test
public void B_testIndexes() {

    // get the full text entity manager
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);

    // create the query using Hibernate Search query DSL
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager
                                .getSearchFactory()
                                .buildQueryBuilder()
                                .forEntity(InspectionMaster.class)
                                .get();

    // Build Query !
    Query query1 = queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("site.siteId").matching("*lpb*").createQuery();
    Query query2 = queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("site.sitedescription").matching("*france*").createQuery();
    Query query3 = queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("vendorNr").matching("*s07610*").createQuery();
    Query query4 = queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("vendorDesc").matching("*limited*").createQuery();
    Query query5 = queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("itemNr").matching("*0023*").createQuery();
    Query query6 = queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("itemDesc").matching("*28w*").createQuery();
    Query query7 = queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("whmPickLocation").matching("*00*").createQuery(); 

    Query query8 = queryBuilder
          .bool()
            .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("site.siteId").matching("*lpb*").createQuery() )
            .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("site.sitedescription").matching("*france*").createQuery() )
            .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("vendorNr").matching("*s07610*").createQuery() )
            .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("vendorDesc").matching("*limited*").createQuery() )
            .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("itemNr").matching("*0023*").createQuery() )
            .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("itemDesc").matching("*28w*").createQuery() )
            .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("whmPickLocation").matching("*00*").createQuery() )
          .createQuery();

    Query query9 = queryBuilder
              .bool()
                .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("site.siteId").matching("*lpb*").createQuery() )
                .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("site.sitedescription").matching("*lpb*").createQuery() )
                .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("vendorNr").matching("*lpb*").createQuery() )
                .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("vendorDesc").matching("*lpb*").createQuery() )
                .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("itemNr").matching("*lpb*").createQuery() )
                .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("itemDesc").matching("*lpb*").createQuery() )
                .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("whmPickLocation").matching("*lpb*").createQuery() )
              .createQuery();


    // wrap Lucene query in an Hibernate Query object
    FullTextQuery jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query1, InspectionMaster.class);
    logService.log("TEST : Test search on site.siteId = *lpb* return " + jpaQuery.getResultSize() + " documents");

    jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query2, InspectionMaster.class);
    logService.log("TEST : Test search on site.sitedescription = *france* return " + jpaQuery.getResultSize() + " documents");

    jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query3, InspectionMaster.class);
    logService.log("TEST : Test search on vendorNr = *s07610* return " + jpaQuery.getResultSize() + " documents");

    jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query4, InspectionMaster.class);
    logService.log("TEST : Test search on vendorDesc = *limited* return " + jpaQuery.getResultSize() + " documents");

    jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query5, InspectionMaster.class);
    logService.log("TEST : Test search on itemNr = *0023* return " + jpaQuery.getResultSize() + " documents");

    jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query6, InspectionMaster.class);
    logService.log("TEST : Test search on itemDesc = *28w* return " + jpaQuery.getResultSize() + " documents");

    jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query7, InspectionMaster.class);
    logService.log("TEST : Test search on whmPickLocation = *00* return " + jpaQuery.getResultSize() + " documents");

    jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query8, InspectionMaster.class);
    logService.log("TEST : Test search on all return " + jpaQuery.getResultSize() + " documents");

    jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query9, InspectionMaster.class);
    logService.log("TEST : Test search on all with *lpb* return " + jpaQuery.getResultSize() + " documents");

}
```

Result work as excepted:

```
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:25:08 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on site.siteId = *lpb* return 16 documents
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:25:08 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on site.sitedescription = *france* return 16 documents
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:25:08 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on vendorNr = *s07610* return 3 documents
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:25:08 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on vendorDesc = *limited* return 1 documents
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:25:08 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on itemNr = *0023* return 4 documents
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:25:08 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on itemDesc = *28w* return 5 documents
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:25:08 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on whmPickLocation = *00* return 10 documents
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:25:08 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on all return 16 documents
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:25:08 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on all with *lpb* return 16 documents
```

I finally build a search function in my project :

```
  public Page<InspectionMaster> search(String text, Pageable pageable) {

        // get the full text entity manager
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);

        // create the query using Hibernate Search query DSL
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager
                                    .getSearchFactory()
                                    .buildQueryBuilder()
                                    .forEntity(InspectionMaster.class)
                                    .get();

        // Add wildcard to always have a full search capability
        text = "*" + text.toLowerCase() + "*";

        // Build Query !
        Query query = queryBuilder
                      .bool()
                        .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("site.siteId").matching(text).createQuery() )
                        .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("site.sitedescription").matching(text).createQuery() )
                        .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("vendorNr").matching(text).createQuery() )
                        .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("vendorDesc").matching(text).createQuery() )
                        .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("itemNr").matching(text).createQuery() )
                        .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("itemDesc").matching(text).createQuery() )
                        .should( queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("whmPickLocation").matching(text).createQuery() )
                      .createQuery();

        // wrap Lucene query in an Hibernate Query object
        FullTextQuery jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, InspectionMaster.class);
        jpaQuery.setFirstResult(pageable.getOffset());
        jpaQuery.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());

        int resultSize = jpaQuery.getResultSize();

        logService.log("Search for text = "+ text +" return " + jpaQuery.getResultSize() + " documents");       

        // execute search and return results (sorted by relevance as default)
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<InspectionMaster> results = jpaQuery.getResultList();      

    return new PageImpl<>(results, pageable, resultSize);
  }
```

But this doesn't work as expected. System return some documents for some keywords, but for others keywords, I get nothing.

I copy/past my test unit code in this function and I get following result :

```
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:23:18 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on site.siteId = *lpb* return 0 documents
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:23:18 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on site.sitedescription = *france* return 0 documents
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:23:18 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on vendorNr = *s07610* return 3 documents
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:23:18 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on vendorDesc = *limited* return 0 documents
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:23:18 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on itemNr = *0023* return 4 documents
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:23:18 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on itemDesc = *28w* return 0 documents
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:23:18 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on whmPickLocation = *00* return 0 documents
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:23:18 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on all return 7 documents
*** LOG [Sat Apr 23 17:23:18 CEST 2016] TEST : Test search on all with *lpb* return 0 documents
```

As you can see, search work for ItemNr and VendorNr, but for others... nothing.

For sure I miss something, but what ???

Any help would be very welcome. Thank in advance.

Comment: I assume your project already has a database. Hibernate Search by default only indexes entities when they are changed: did you trigger a MassIndexer to have it re-index everything?

Comment: Hi Sanne. Thank you very much, I just add fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait(); during ContextLoaderListener. And now all work fine.

Comment: That is strange in fact. When JUnit start application, index is updated. When it's the normal process, no update. In more, strange there is no persistence of index ? But ok, all work fine now. Thank you again.